# How to get a value from a promise and store it in a variable for further use

Tags: javascript, promise, testcafe

How to get a value from a promise and store it in a variable for further use.

I am expecting my method to return a passoword as string rather than a  resolved promise object. I need passoword string so that I can pass it to httpAuth function given below. httpAuth() is from TestCafe automation framework

Test.js code:

```
let mypass=Utils.returnPwd(); //I am using returnPwd() from Utils.js file that's returning a password.

fixture`Automated Test1`
    .meta('fixturepack', 'regression')
    .page("http://intranetURL")
    .beforeEach(async t => {             
        DriverManager.setDriver(t);
        await DriverManager.maximize();         
    })
    .httpAuth({
        username: 'loginuser1',
        password:  mypass
    })
```

Utils.js code:

```
  async base64Decoding(encodedPassword) {        
    var decodedData = Buffer.from(encodedPassword, 'base64').toString('ascii'); 
    var decodedPassword = decodedData.toString()
    console.log(decodedPassword);
    return decodedPassword;
    }

    async returnPwd(){
        let mypass2= this.base64Decoding('A2dIOEhBfXYvfSNba');        
       return mypass2.then(function(){ })
    }
```

Current error:
credentials.password is expected to be a string, but it was object.

> .httpAuth({
> username: 'loginuser1',
> password:  mypass
> })

Comment: Why is `base64Decoding` declared as `async`? I don't see anything in there that would require that. Same goes for `returnPwd`

Comment: @Barmar Not sure that's a fitting duplicate?

Comment: Declaring a function `async` makes it return a Promise. Why did you expect it to return the password instead? You can use `let  mypass = await Utils.returnPwd()` if the caller is also an `async` function, otherwise you have to resolve the promise.

Comment: @Barmar This question isn't *really* about Promises though. Neither of these methods is supposed to be `async` in the first place, and removing the keyword from both will immediately fix the problem.

Comment: @ChrisG That's true, I didn't really look at what the functions are doing.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar ,Chris G ,Rajdeep Debnath  . Issue resolved after making the method as synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see any `async` code in Untils.js, you can make it synchronous

```
//Test.js
let mypass = Utils.returnPwd();

//Utils.js
base64Decoding(encodedPassword) {        
    var decodedData = Buffer.from(encodedPassword, 'base64').toString('ascii'); 
    var decodedPassword = decodedData.toString()
    console.log(decodedPassword);
    return decodedPassword;
    }

    returnPwd(){
        let mypass2= this.base64Decoding('A2dIOEhBfXYvfSNba');        
       return mypass2;
    }
```